# undefined reference to '__imp___..' SFML C++ library

Tags: c++, sfml

I just decided to try and understand the GUI user interface for C++, and found out that SFML is pretty good for beginners.
I also use CodeBlocks binary release (I guess)
I found a tutorial showing how to link the SFML library to codeblocks.
I followed it exactly.

took their sample program, tried to build it (compiled just fine)

and I got 20 errors

[image]

this is the code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And these are the changes I've made:

[image]

I've never worked with these things, and I am at a complete loss.
Sorry for maybe being an inappropriate question, but I couldn't find any relevant answer to my question yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link it in linker settings 
-lsfml-graphics 
-lsfml-window 
-lsfml-system

Try using those in codeblocks undefined reference is usually a linker error

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't linked correctly.

Check out [this official tutorial](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.2/start-cb.php) and read it very carefully (especially the red boxes).

There's also a table if you scroll to the bottom that lists all additional necessary dependencies when you use SFML_STATIC.